Unitary Operator action on a state
I have a state $| {\psi} \rangle$ which is acted upon by an unitary operator $e^{ia\hat{x}}$
i.e $$e^{ia\hat{x}}| {\psi} \rangle$$
How does this action take place? Is it similar to the position operator where we just have the multiplication of the corresponding position coordinate from the wave function with the wave function?

With the last sentence, do you mean how you should think of $\mathrm{e}^{\hat{x}}|\psi\rangle$ in terms of $\hat{x}|\psi\rangle=x|\psi\rangle$?

Yes it's similar. When you have a function of an operator like in an exponential, the way that it works is to expand the operator in its taylor series. That is the same taylor series as if the exponential were just a function, and not an operator - this is essentially the definition of that operator.
For the position operator this seems kind of pointless because it's literally just a function anyway. But imagine you have a derivative operator instead of $\hat{x}$ - then you wouldn't know how to use it until you expand the exponential in a taylor series.

@KyleKanos Yes, this is what I am thinking!

Do you appreciate $\langle x| e^{ia\hat x}|\psi\rangle= e^{iax} \psi(x)$ ?

@Mt then it's mostly what don'ttrainaionme said: $\exp(A)=1+A+A^2/2+A^3/6+\cdots$ for any $A$; then just act on $|\psi\rangle$ and see what comes up.
